# linux memtester which cover near all physical memory

Tags: linux, testing, memory

I'm looking for a memtester which would cover as large a part as possible of physical memory in a running machine which doesn't have an ECC RAM. It should test memory in chunks. For example: allocate 100MB, test it, release it, allocate another 100MB... I know that some regions of memory are already allocated so kernel has to reallocate them.

I found that [this](http://pyropus.ca/software/memtester/) product has an option to specify the physical location but it doesn't work because mmap() function doesn't allocate specified location. I would get the solution if I modified the kernel but that still doesn't solve the problem because some sections are already allocated.

I think that this is a known problem, so is there anyone who already solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Memtest86 is probably the way to go, you can boot it from a ramdisk. We have used it for years to test memory in the factory.

http://www.memtest.org/

Comment: I know but the main idea is that if you have machine which is running 24/7 without ECC RAM (for eg. raspberry pi) and is not critical machine you don't know when RAM become broken. So I want to find the product which is doing that on the fly or way to develop it. Thanks :)